# Extract tgz with subfolders java

Tags: java, compression, gzip, tar

I have a file `archive.tgz`, which consists of several subfolders storing xml files. I want to iterate through all files from the and parse the xml files. The file directory is structured as follows.

```
01/
    01.xml
    02.xml
02/
    03.xml
```

Here is the Java code I tried already, but when I try the getFile method the file is always zero. I also tried getting an directory from one of the entries and get the subfiles from that and get a file from the absolute path.

```
    while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry) tarIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (entry.isFile()) {
            entry.getFile();
            // Parse xml but this is null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TarArchiveEntry#getFile` cannot do it. Instead, try with `TarArchiveInputStream` to read the data:

```
byte[] data = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
tarIn.read(data);
```

After you get the `data`, you can parse your xml.